SQL Server 2014 Медленно работает в WINDOWS 10
у меня есть программа который работает с SQL server СУБД. Она работает в Windows 7 Супер с совместимостю Windows Server 2008. Но когда я устанавливаю на 10ку с совместимостю Windows Vista (так как нет совместимость Windows Server 2008) то программа который работает с сервером медленно работает? Это из за чего может быть есть ли решение для этого?

10-ка на том же железе? / Если уж переезжаете с одной ОС на другую, то рассмотрите переход на новую версию SQL Server. / Запускайте утилиты мониторинга. Потом, как данные накопятся, смотрите, что они покажут, где узкие места, какие советы по улучшению будут предложены.

Что, если задать настройку производительности в пользу Background Services? Полагаю, в Win Server'е она задана по умолчанию.
